# speed up a monte carlo simulation with nested loop in R

Tags: r, nested-loops, montecarlo

I would like to speed up the below monte carlo simulation of a DEA estimate

```
A<-nrow(banks)
effm<-matrix(nrow=A, ncol=2)
m<-20
B<-100

pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0,
                     max = A, style=3)
for(a in 1:A) {
  x1<-x[-a,]
  y1<-y[-a,]
  theta=matrix(nrow=B,ncol=1) 

  for(i in 1:B){

    xrefm<-x1[sample(1:nrow(x1),m,replace=TRUE),]
    yrefm<-y1[sample(1:nrow(y1),m,replace=TRUE),]
    theta[i,]<-dea(matrix(x[a,],ncol=3),
                   matrix(y[a,],ncol=3),
                   RTS='vrs',ORIENTATION='graph',
                   xrefm,yrefm,FAST=TRUE)
  }

  effm[a,1]=mean(theta)
  effm[a,2]=apply(theta,2,sd)/sqrt(B)
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, a) 
}
close(pb)
effm
```

Once A becomes large the simulation freezes.  i am aware from online research that the apply function rapidly speeds up such code but am not sure how to use it in the above procedure.

Any help/direction would be much appreciated

Barry

Comment: There's a lot of misinformation online.  The `apply` function may or may not be faster than a for loop; it depends on what you're doing.  You need to profile your code for speed to see what portions are slowest (see `?Rprof`), then you will know what needs to be faster.  People could help profile your code if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich ditto!  also, if you can post portions of the data you're using, we will be able to actually run your code which makes it much easier to help

Comment: Can you define "freeze" ?   There's a big difference between a process that takes a long time, and one which blows out system memory (or something) and hangs up the process and/or the entire OS.

Comment: Would be helpful if we could run this code locally. What is `banks`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be faster.... but if you're locking up when A is large that might be a memory issue and the following is more memory intensive.  More information, like what `banks` is, what `x` is, `y`, where you get `dea` from, and what the purpose is would be helpful.

Essentially all I've done is try to move as much as I can out of the inner loop.  The shorter that is, the better off you'll be.

```
A <- nrow(banks)
effm <- matrix(nrow = A, ncol = 2)
m <- 20
B <- 100
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0,
                     max = A, style=3)
for(a in 1:A) {
  x1 <- x[-a,]
  y1 <- y[-a,]
  theta <- numeric(B)
  xrefm <- x1[sample(1:nrow(x1), m * B, replace=TRUE),] # get all of your samples at once
  yrefm <- y1[sample(1:nrow(y1), m * B, replace=TRUE),]
  deaX <- matrix(x[a,], ncol=3)
  deaY <- matrix(y[a,], ncol=3)

  for(i in 1:B){
    theta[i] <- dea(deaX, deaY, RTS = 'vrs', ORIENTATION = 'graph',
                   xrefm[(1:m) + (i-1) * m,], yrefm[(1:m) + (i-1) * m,], FAST=TRUE)
  }

  effm[a,1] <- mean(theta)
  effm[a,2] <- sd(theta) / sqrt(B)
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, a) 
}
close(pb)
effm
```

Comment: It would be faster still if you create the first two arguments to `dea` before the second loop.

Comment: For that matter, `xynrow<-nrow(x1);mB<-m*B` and rewriting as  `xrefm <- x1[sample(1:xynrow, mB, replace=TRUE),]`  will remove a massive number of calculations from your task.

Comment: @John I guess dea is from benchmarking package, but can you explain in 2 sentences your idea to perform the code?

Comment: Thanks for all useful comments so far and apologies for some of the vagueness in my post.My code is running the order M hyperbolic efficiency estimation, where

Comment: Thanks for all useful comments/code suggestions so far and apologies for some of the vagueness in my post. Banks is dataframe of 1394 bank observations, x is a 1394 x 3 matrix of inputs and y is 1394 matrix of outputs, while DEA is from benchmarking.  I am trying to run an order M hyperbolic efficiency estimation where the unit (each bank in this case) being analysed is left out of the reference set in the DEA estimation.

Comment: What i mean by freezing is that the code hangs in R but does effect the OS processing power.

Comment: I will attempt to great a reproducible copy of the process and hopefully this will make it easier to provide advice... Should i then create a new question or add to this stream as an extra comment ?

Comment: @john thanks alot for you code modification but unfortunately it produces an error  "Error in dea(deaArg1, deaArg2, RTS = "vrs", ORIENTATION = "graph", xrefm[(1:m) +  : 
  Number of inputs must be the same in X and XREF"

Comment: hard to debug without x... You can delete comments you cannot edit.  You should be putting lots of this in your question and deleting comments.

Comment: @john yes works now but R still hangs at about 31% of the process